Game combining board games and people walking around the park on a split screen (for Android)
I am looking for a game for Android smartphones and tablets where the screen is divided into two parts.
On the left, you move characters around a park. They also move somewhat, autonomously, but not much, even released.
On the right, a board game.
The person switches between the board game on the right and the characters that move around the park on the left, without swapping windows.
This enables the user to cater attention to current desire (and also, have fun, while waiting for the other player's move in the case of games with two players).
Thanks.
